# What Ever Happened to Hologram AF?

Tags: flash, autofocus, sony, laser

I'm currently using it in my Sony DSC-F828 and I think works very well especially in low light condition. I've read a lot of hypothesis about it but anyone know for sure why modern cameras don't use it anymore?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the "hologram" AF was simply a contrast based system that shined a laser on the subject to get accurate measurements.  It was limited to only a few meters.  Modern phase detection AF is much faster and with the use of IR illuminators (which serve a similar purpose to the laser) they are able to focus in near total or total darkness at a much longer range due to their increased sensitivity.

Comment: But phase detection works only for reflex, hologram AF were used for bridge camera, for me it worked great..